# Parse a string containing date and time in a custom format

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, time

I have a string of the next format `"ORDER20100322194007"`, where `20100322` is a date and `194007` is a time. How to parse a string and get the contained `DateTime` object?

Comment: Thats a good question. Maybe you should change the title to something like "DateTime parsing of custom date format in .NET"

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Will it always start with `ORDER`?

```
string pattern = "'ORDER'yyyyMMddHHmmss";
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(text, pattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                           DateTimeStyles.None,
                           out dt))
{
    // dt is the parsed value
} 
else 
{
    // Invalid string
}
```

If the string being invalid should throw an exception, then use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) instead of [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx)

If it doesn't always begin with "ORDER" then do whatever you need to in order to get just the date and time part, and remove "'ORDER'" from the format pattern above.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) method to specify the format that should be used while parsing.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a fixed structure of your string say order will not always be there then you can use regex to separate the numbers and characters and then use convert to datetime function for the numbers separated.