# Datetime.TryParse can't parse yyyy/MM/dd format

Tags: c#, datetime, tryparse

I am at the moment trying to convert a date given in the format as `yyyy/MM/dd`.
To check if a valid Date is given.

```
if(!DateTime.TryParse(textBoxDatumVanStorting.Text, out Test2))
```

Is what im using at the moment but it always gives me a wrong date.

I have Looked in to using `DateTime.TryParseExact`.
But cant seem to get this to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DateTime parsing of custom date format in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560540/datetime-parsing-of-custom-date-format-in-net)

Comment: What is _wrong date_ exactly? What is your `textBoxDatumVanStorting.Text` and your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: Well the Format im using is yyyy/MM/dd.
textBoxDatumVanStorting.Text contains 1994/09/27 as date.
But Tryparse is unable to parse the format im using .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Specifying a Format**

Consider using the [`DateTime.TryParseExact()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) method which will allow you to explicitly define the format your string is in :

```
// This will attempt to parse your date in exactly the format provided
if(!DateTime.TryParseExact(textBoxDatumVanStorting.Text,"yyyy/MM/dd", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out Date2))
{
    // Your date is not valid, consider doing something
}
```

**A Matter of Culture**

In the above example, the third parameter being passed in represents the specific culture / format that you expect to use to parse the date. Using `null` will default to the current culture, but if you need to explicitly specify this, you can do so here as seen using the invariant culture :

```
Date output;
if(!DateTime.TryParseExact(input,"yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out output))  
{
     // Uh oh again...
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked.
Only had to change DateTimeStyles.None to System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None

Comment: @Blasje - You can add `using System.Globalization` at the top of your file so you won't need to type so much code.

Answer (score 0):

If `DateTime.TryParse` *can't* parse your string, that means this `yyyy/MM/dd` format is not a standard date format for your `CurrentCulture`.

You can use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact) with custom format like;

```
DateTime Test2;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(textBoxDatumVanStorting.Text, "yyyy/MM/dd", 
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                           DateTimeStyles.None, out Test2))
{
    // Successfull parse
}
```