# Formatting a Date String with a ForEach Loop using string.Insert

Tags: c#, foreach

I am working on changing these strings into this format yyyy-mm-ddhh:mm:ss

I put the strings into an array, fed it into a four each loop where I am using the Insert() function to add the "-" and ":" in the appropriate positions but it is still printing out the original strings.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] dates =  { "20190127144251", "20190127123315", "20190127035942" };

        foreach (string i in dates)
        {
            string str = i;
            str.Insert(3, "-");
            str.Insert(5, "-");
            str.Insert(7, "-");
            str.Insert(9, ":");
            str.Insert(11, ":");


            Console.WriteLine(i);

        }


    }
}
```

Printing out the original string, not formatted

Comment: strings are immutable. `.Insert` returns a new string.

Comment: You should take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2560540/416574) question as it shows you how to use `DateTime.TryParseExact`. I would recommend parsing into a DateTime object and then use the ToString method with your format string.

Answer (score 4):

First, you're not storing the result of your `.Insert()` calls.  Strings are immutable and modifications to them aren't in place but rather return the new modified string.  Put the result in the variable:

```
str = str.Insert(3, "-");
// etc.
```

Second, you're outputting `i` intead of `str`.  Output the one you're modifying:

```
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Third, you can skip all of this by parsing the string into an actual `DateTime` and [formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) its output:

```
foreach (string i in dates)
{
    var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(i, "yyyyMMddhhmmss");
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-hh:mm:ss"));
}
```

Which gives you much cleaner code with more clear intent, rather than counting string indexes and inserting individual characters.