# Convert Oct 27 2022 9:09:50:693PM into c# dateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

How to convert below DateTime into C# (mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss)

`Oct 27 2022  9:09:50:693PM`

> Error string was not in recognized format

Tried with below code:

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
DateTime LastUpdateDate = DateTime.Parse("Oct 27 2022  9:09:50:693PM", cultureInfo, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse a string containing date and time in a custom format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560540/parse-a-string-containing-date-and-time-in-a-custom-format)

Comment: note that `mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss` is not "C# DateTime", that would be a _string representation_ of an existing DateTime, in en-US locale. `DateTime`is an abstraction, that has no intrinsic string format, until you call `ToString` or similar on it.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netcore-3.1#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) with `"MMM dd yyyy  h:mm:ss:ffftt"` format,

```
using System;
using System.Globalization; 
...   

var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
DateTime LastUpdateDate = DateTime.ParseExact("Oct 27 2022  9:09:50:693PM", "MMM dd yyyy  h:mm:ss:ffftt", cultureInfo);
Console.WriteLine(LastUpdateDate.ToString());
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EmRyZq)

---

**Note:** You have two spaces between year and time. No space between milliseconds and AM/PM designator.
Please check your string date and time and update format(Spaces in `DateTime` format) accordingly

---

MSDN documentation for [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)